# Requests doesnt retrieve the site after post request

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I want to scrape data from this site: https://ispu.mgipu.hr/

Here is the procedure (after zooming to 1:5000 at least):

1. You have to click on the symbol on the right that has a square, triangle, and circle.
2. Then you have to click below 'Info lokacija'.
3. Then you have to choose 'Poligonom' above 'Odabir'.
4. Now you have to drow anything with the mouse (double click when you are finished).

If you check the network you can see a new request appear: 'obuhvat'.

I tried to make POST requests directly to the same site but I always get the answer that my body is empty.

I only works if I first do everything in the browser and that repeat request in python.

Here is my try:

```
s = requests.Session()
s.get('https://ispu.mgipu.hr/')
data = {
    "geom":"POLYGON((460050.4401008804 5073385.306770615,460196.600393201 5073256.506513015,460327.64065528155 5073458.106916216,460183.16036632087 5073556.107112216,460050.4401008804 5073385.306770615))"
    }
s.post('https://ispu.mgipu.hr/geo/api/info-lokacija/obuhvat',
       data=json.dumps(data))
```

Comment: You missed to ask a question. Make sure it is specific enough for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I would like to retrieve output of ''obuhvat'' request. You can to run the code. It doesnt work. Steps explain how to what steps i want to automate.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have to put "json" instead of "data" (and put a header). The following code works for me:

```
import requests as rq

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:86.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/86.0"}
url = "https://ispu.mgipu.hr/geo/api/info-lokacija/obuhvat"
data = {
    "geom":"POLYGON((460050.4401008804 5073385.306770615,460196.600393201 5073256.506513015,460327.64065528155 5073458.106916216,460183.16036632087 5073556.107112216,460050.4401008804 5073385.306770615))"
    }
resp = rq.post(url, json=data, headers=headers)
```

No need to put a "get" query and create a session beforehand.

The post request doesn't send you back much informations, other than a change in CRS...

Bye

Comment: thanks for the reply. Your code works because I have already drawn a polygon on the website. If you change only one numbering the `data` argument (for example 460050.4401008804 to 460050.4401008805, last number) it doesn't work! I don't understand why it doesn't work if I change one number. It returns 400 status code.